# Trigger Gitlab-ci from aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, slack

Im looking for lambda that can trigger Gitlab-ci pipeline to deploy specific branches and send results to slack.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Trigger a pipeline

As per [GitLab Trigger API manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline):

> To trigger a job you need to send a `POST` request to GitLab’s API endpoint:
>
> ```
>     curl -X POST <API url>/projects/<your_awesome_gitlab_project>/trigger/pipeline
> ```
>
> The required parameters are the [trigger’s `token`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#authentication-tokens) and the Git `ref` on which the trigger will be performed. Valid refs are the branch and the tag. The `:id` of a project can be found by [querying the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) or by visiting the **CI/CD** settings page which provides self-explanatory examples.

## Watching a pipeline

To check pipeline results, use [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html):

> You can set up a rule to run an AWS Lambda function on a schedule. This tutorial shows how to use the AWS Management Console or the AWS CLI to create the rule. If you would like to use the AWS CLI but have not installed it, see the [AWS Command Line Interface User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/).

To check jobs status, use: [Get a single pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline) or [List project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) API calls.

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: " "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/46"

## Inform on `Slack`

To send `Slack` notifications with `lambda`, use this tutorial:

[Creating an AWS Lambda Function and API Endpoint | Slack](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/aws-lambda)

## Two cents about endpoint security

CI Trigger is secured by [token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#authentication-tokens). In general, it's enough for securing your endpoints.

But, if the approach isn't enough, there are some techniques to "hide" endpoints:

- client [IP whitelisting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/ip_whitelist.html)  with `GitLab`
- `AWS` `Security Groups` [for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) or [for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)
- [Securing URLs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus/) with `Nginx` or with [HAProxy](https://serverfault.com/a/800176/530021)

Comment: Can you suggest something to make it secure? I don't what to expose my CI Trigger on the Internet like that.may be something like the user should be logged in to GitLab to trigger pipeline or other authentication mechanisms. I went through docs but couldn't find anything. If anyone can help that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @krishnaa208 basic CI Trigger is secured by [token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#authentication-tokens). If the approach isn't enough for you, there are some techniques to "hide" your endpoints: (1) client [IP whitelisting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/ip_whitelist.html) (2) AWS Security Groups [for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) or [for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) (3) [Securing URLs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus/)

Comment: This only works from another pipeline. Not from Lambda